# Is it possible to store historical data from application insights analytics query to use in Power BI?

Tags: azure, analytics, powerbi, azure-application-insights

I have made a nice application insights analytics query, which I use for my Power BI report. But the data goes only 9 days back in time. After 9 days the data is removed. Is there a way to store those results to build up more historical data?

I started with some stream analytics, but then I have to make another query in another language. I think that is a waste of time.

Is there a way to use my analytics query and have historical data?

Comment: SO isn't the place to ask product questions, it's a Q&A site for *programming* questions.  Your question is fully answered in the documentation and product site. If you want longer data retention, you pay. There's a very handy wizard for this. BTW stream analytics has nothing to do with extracting data, it's meant to *analyze* streams of events. Finally, if you have continuous export, you *don't* need anything else to export the data

Comment: Sidenote: why is it  a waste of time to learn something new if it fits the purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the rest SDK can help you? https://dev.applicationinsights.io/. You can create queries and store the result wherever you want. Like Azure Blob Storage or Azure Table Storage and use that as input for Power BI.

Answer (score 0):

If you need *raw* data after the initial time it is stored, you'd need to use something like the "Continuous Export" feature to export your data to your own storage/analysis pipeline:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-export-telemetry/

then you can store your data for as long as you want.